# Cannot load a model in codeigniter with wamp

Tags: codeigniter, model, wamp

I can't load my model into my controller. The Model (deling_model.php) code:

```
<?php
class Deling_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct(){
    $this->load->database();
}

public function get_personne()
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM PERSONNE;');
    return $query->result_array();
}
}
```

And my controller (deling.php) code:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Deling extends CI_Controller
{

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('deling_model')or die("error");
}

public function index()
    {
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
        $this->load->view('superAdmin/header');
        $this->load->view('templates/presentation');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }else{
        $this->connexion();
    }
}

public function connexion()
    {
        [...]
    }
}
```

When I launch the application,  there is an error. The controller cannot load the model what I try to load. When I put a wrong model name, there is a codeigniter error but when I put the good name, I have printed "error" in my page.

Comment: what is printed error you get?

Comment: There is no error if I keep: "$this->load->model('deling_model');"
Just that the model is not loaded. I can't use my functions.
If I load in this way: "$this->load->model('deling_model')or die("error");", there is nothing except a blank page with the word "error".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add database library to auto load libraries array.

In autoload.php file which can be found at codeigniter_folder/application/config/autoload.php

search for this line:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array();
```

then add database:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

**Edit**

Apparently your problem because of `or die`,I just tried to add it after working model and it shows "error".

So I suggest you to remove it after your model loading.

Comment: But when I remove "or die", the first part works (whitout functions), but when I call functions that are in the model, I have this error: "Call to undefined method Deling_model::get_usr() in [...] "
(get_usr() is one of many functions that there are in the model)

Comment: how do you call get_usr() function in your controller?

Comment: $data['listeUsers'] = $this->deling_model->get_usr();

Comment: Try to add back `or die` and see the result.
I think that was the main problem in first place.

Comment: Yes it was the "or die". But I have keep the old function name in the model and did not correspond with the call. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this:

```
<?php
class Deling_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct(){
parent::__construct();
$this->load->database();
}

public function get_personne()
{
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM PERSONNE;');
return $query->result_array();
}
}
```

Comment: and empty blank page seems that the database is not loaded can you also try: $this->load->model('Model_name', '', TRUE);

Comment: Yes I tried with $this->load->model('Model_name', '', TRUE); or the parent in the __construct, but still nothing..

Comment: please add ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); at the beginning of the controller file after <?php tag to see the full error description

Comment: Thanks for the response but I think the problem is solve ! :)